# Android app WebServices issues with XML

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I have issues showing the webservice data in the application I'm trying to call the data in a TextView but it  not happening.

I'm 100% sure that the webservices are OK even if I press one button action, changes the database logging (insert, update, delete)

webservices written in JSON

maybe the problem is with my XML code?

excuse my English

Java Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button consultar;
Button consultarporid;
Button insertar;
Button actualizar;
Button borrar;
EditText idendificador;
EditText nombre;
EditText direccion;
TextView resultado;


// IP de mi Url
String IP = "http://bdandroidtuto.esy.es/";
// Rutas de los Web Services
String GET = IP + "/obtener_alumnos.php";
String GET_BY_ID = IP + "/obtener_alumno_por_id.php";
String UPDATE = IP + "/actualizar_alumno.php";
String DELETE = IP + "/borrar_alumno.php";
String INSERT = IP + "/insertar_alumno.php";

ObtenerWebService hiloconexion;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Enlaces con elementos visuales del XML

    consultar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.consultar);
    consultarporid = (Button)findViewById(R.id.consultarid);
    insertar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.insertar);
    actualizar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.actualizar);
    borrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.borrar);
    idendificador = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eid);
    nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enombre);
    direccion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edireccion);
    resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultado);

    // Listener de los botones

    consultar.setOnClickListener(this);
    consultarporid.setOnClickListener(this);
    insertar.setOnClickListener(this);
    actualizar.setOnClickListener(this);
    borrar.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.consultar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(GET,"1");   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground

            break;
        case R.id.consultarid:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            String cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID + "?idalumno=" + idendificador.getText().toString();
            hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada,"2");   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        case R.id.insertar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(INSERT,"3",nombre.getText().toString(),direccion.getText().toString());   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        case R.id.actualizar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(UPDATE,"4",idendificador.getText().toString(),nombre.getText().toString(),direccion.getText().toString());   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        case R.id.borrar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(DELETE,"5",idendificador.getText().toString());   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
}

public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String cadena = params[0];
        URL url = null; // Url de donde queremos obtener información
        String devuelve ="";



        if(params[1]=="1"){    // Consulta de todos los alumnos

            try {
                url = new URL(cadena);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                        " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){


                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  // preparo la cadena de entrada

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                    // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                    // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a traves de un
                    // StringBuilder.

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON



                    if (resultJSON=="1"){      // hay alumnos a mostrar
                        JSONArray alumnosJSON = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("alumno");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                        for(int i=0;i<alumnosJSON.length();i++){
                            devuelve = devuelve + alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("idalumno") + " " +
                                    alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre") + " " +
                                    alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("direccion") + "\n";

                        }

                    }
                    else if (resultJSON=="2"){
                        devuelve = "No hay alumnos";
                    }


                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;


        }
        else if(params[1]=="2"){    // consulta por id

            try {
                url = new URL(cadena);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                        " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){


                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  // preparo la cadena de entrada

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                    // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                    // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a traves de un
                    // StringBuilder.

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON=="1"){      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = devuelve + respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("idAlumno") + " " +
                                respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("nombre") + " " +
                                respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("direccion");

                    }
                    else if (resultJSON=="2"){
                        devuelve = "No hay alumnos";
                    }

                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;


        }
        else if(params[1]=="3"){    // insert

            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                DataOutputStream printout;
                DataInputStream input;
                url = new URL(cadena);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConn.connect();
                //Creo el Objeto JSON
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("nombre", params[2]);
                jsonParam.put("direccion", params[3]);
                // Envio los parámetros post.
                OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();


                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        //response+=line;
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON == "1") {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = "Alumno insertado correctamente";

                    } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                        devuelve = "El alumno no pudo insertarse";
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;


        }
        else if(params[1]=="4"){    // update

            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                DataOutputStream printout;
                DataInputStream input;
                url = new URL(cadena);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConn.connect();
                //Creo el Objeto JSON
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("idalumno",params[2]);
                jsonParam.put("nombre", params[3]);
                jsonParam.put("direccion", params[4]);
                // Envio los parámetros post.
                OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();


                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        //response+=line;
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON == "1") {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = "Alumno actualizado correctamente";

                    } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                        devuelve = "El alumno no pudo actualizarse";
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;

        }
        else if(params[1]=="5") {    // delete

            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                DataOutputStream printout;
                DataInputStream input;
                url = new URL(cadena);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConn.connect();
                //Creo el Objeto JSON
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("idalumno", params[2]);
                // Envio los parámetros post.
                OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();


                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        //response+=line;
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON == "1") {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = "Alumno borrado correctamente";

                    } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                        devuelve = "No hay alumnos";
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String s) {
        super.onCancelled(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        resultado.setText(s);
        //super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }



}

}
```

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.rwa.jsontest.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Consultar"
        android:id="@+id/consultar" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Consultar ID"
        android:id="@+id/consultarid" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insertar"
        android:id="@+id/insertar" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Borrar"
        android:id="@+id/borrar" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Actualizar"
        android:id="@+id/actualizar" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Identificador"
        android:id="@+id/tid" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eid" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:id="@+id/tnombre" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/enombre" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Direccion"
        android:id="@+id/tdireccion" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edireccion" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not at all clear on your problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: http://bdandroidtuto.esy.es/obtener_alumnos.php
this is Json working. In my android app I have (Show, show by id, insert, delete, update) they are working perfectly with json but are not displaying data in the form

Comment: So the problem is how to update a TextView with a value?

Comment: Exactly! i just want display the data in the textview, get all records with the first button "Consultar" and get record by ID "Consultar ID"

Comment: So what's the problem? Did you call `setText`?

Comment: in onPostExecute.. yes ! but is not working

Comment: It would be easier if could edit your question to just show the parts of the code that aren't working. Right now there's a lot of code to look through.